# Android clock widget: how do I invoke buildUpdate() every minute (a.k.a. synchronize with clock)?

Tags: android, widget, clock

I have a class that extends AppWidgetProvider that provides the content for my widget. This is a clock widget so I want to make sure that buildUpdate() is invoked exactly on the minute, every minute. How can I add this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the source code from [this project](http://code.google.com/p/24clock/). 
Basically the idea is to have a Service running in background to update the widget.

Comment: Not possible now if targeting oreo